# Carriage return being added when uploading file using ssh.net

Tags: ssh

I am using the Renci ssh.net library to upload a file from a Windows device to a Linux node. Before uploading the file I looked at in NotePad++ and at the end of each line was only a LF character. But after uploading the file there is a CRLF character at the end of each line. How can I preserve just the LF character when using Renci ssh.net library?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code that you're using to transfer this file. Plain ssh doesn't include file transfer capabilities per se, so I presume you're either using SFTP, SCP, or else running some program on the server to receive a file? Please describe exactly what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use binary mode, that will transfer files without these weird conversions. If you want some code, please provide yours.

Answer (score 0):

I am super late to the conversation, but my issue was very similar to Ron's.

Long story short, I was using

```
var file = _sftpClient.CreateText($"{remoteFilePath}/{fileName}");
file.WriteLine(fileContent);
file.Close();
```

Instead of

```
var file = _sftpClient.CreateText($"{remoteFilePath}/{fileName}");
file.Write(fileContent);
file.Close();
```

If someone writes to a file one line at a time, it can reproduce the issue that was described in the question.